# CMake must be installed to build dlib even after installing Cmake and setting environmental variable

Tags: python, cmake, dlib

CMake must be installed to build dlib even after installing Cmake and setting environmental variable. Can anyone please help me I am stuck in this issue since 4 days :(

Answer (score 0):

Kindly see this thread. It will be more helpful if you post the screenshot of the issue.

[Cmake issue Solving](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73032883/12908583)

Answer (score 0):

You can do these commands :

```
pip install cmake (or pip3 install cmake)
```

On Debian-based system

```
sudo apt install cmake
```

On Mac

```
brew install cmake
```